# Citations disappearing in in main text

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am struggling to find a solution to my problem. I have a bibliography.bib file that contains all of my sources. In the main text file I have the following code to insert the bibliography.

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,bibliography}
```

for some reason, only some of my sources are appearing in the bibliography and others are simply blank.
[image: image of compiled documents bibliography]

Most references are showing up just fine and are being cited in the paper correctly, I'm not sure why not all of them are showing up.

Here is the code in my bibliography.bib. I do \cite{} all reference. I still get an error in two lines: the @misc{medical ventilator... (error: I was expecting a ',' or a '}')and %   CTLuse_article_number     = "yes", (error: you're missing a field name) lines.

```
% IEEEexample.bib 
% V1.12 (2007/01/11)
% Copyright (c) 2002-2007 by Michael Shell

% Some entries call strings that are defined in the IEEEabrv.bib file.
% Therefore, IEEEabrv.bib should be loaded prior to this file. 
% Usage: 

% \bibliographystyle{./IEEEtran}
% \bibliography{./IEEEabrv,./IEEEexample}


% *************************************************************************
% Legal Notice:...

%% Arrange in alphabetical order
@article{khoo2000physiological,
  title={Physiological Control Systems: Analysis, Simulation and Estimation.},
  author={Khoo, Michael CK},
  journal={CONTROL SYSTEMS},
  pages={1},
  year={2000},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}

@article{al2015modelling,
  title={Modelling and Simulation of Pressure Controlled Mechanical Ventilation System},
  author={Al-Naggar, Noman Q and others},
  journal={Journal of Biomedical Science and Engineering},
  volume={8},
  number={10},
  pages={707},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Scientific Research Publishing}
}
@incollection{duke2011airway,
  title={Airway Management},
  author={Duke, James},
  booktitle={Anesthesia Secrets},
  pages={58--67},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

 @misc{mountsinai, title={Repurposing bi-level ventilators for use with intubated patients while minimizing risk to health care works during insufficient supply of conventional ventilation for patients with COVID-19}, url={https://health.mountsinai.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/14/2020/04/NIV-to-Ventilator-Modification-Protocol-v1.02-for-posting.pdf}, publisher={Mount Sinai Health System}, author={Mount Sinai Health System}, year={2020}, month={Apr}}

  @misc{lee_2020, title={A NYC hospital has figured out how to turn sleep apnea machines it got from Elon Musk into ventilators for coronavirus patients}, url={https://www.businessinsider.com/nyc-hospital-mount-sinai-turns-sleep-apnea-machines-into-ventilators-2020-4}, journal={Business Insider}, publisher={Business Insider}, author={Lee, Yeji Jesse}, year={2020}, month={Apr}}

   @misc{yang_2020, title={Turning sleep apnea machines into ventilators}, url={https://engineering.berkeley.edu/news/2020/04/turning-sleep-apnea-machines-into-ventilators/}, journal={Berkeley Engineering}, publisher={Berkeley Engineering}, author={Yang, Sarah}, year={2020}, month={Apr}}

    @misc{healy_2020, title={Ventilators for coronavirus patients are in short supply. How scientists might pivot}, url={https://www.latimes.com/science/story/2020-04-07/researchers-look-for-ways-to-divert-patients-from-ventilators-as-shortage-looms}, journal={Los Angeles Times}, publisher={Los Angeles Times}, author={Healy, Melissa}, year={2020}, month={Apr}}

     @misc{johnshopkins, title={COVID-19 Map}, url={https://coronavirus.jhu.edu/map.html}, journal={Johns Hopkins Coronavirus Resource Center}, publisher={Johns Hopkins Coronavirus Resource Center}}

 @misc{halpern_tan_2020, title={SCCM: United States Resource Availability for COVID-19}, url={https://sccm.org/Blog/March-2020/United-States-Resource-Availability-for-COVID-19}, journal={Society of Critical Care Medicine (SCCM)}, publisher={Society of Critical Care Medicine (SCCM)}, author={Halpern, Neil A and Tan, Kay See}, year={2020}, month={Mar}}

  @misc{kliff_satariano_silver-greenberg_kulish_2020, title={There Aren't Enough Ventilators to Cope With the Coronavirus}, url={https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/18/business/coronavirus-ventilator-shortage.html}, journal={The New York Times}, publisher={The New York Times}, author={Kliff, Sarah and Satariano, Adam and Silver-greenberg, Jessica and Kulish, Nicholas}, year={2020}, month={Mar}}

   @misc{asa, title={CPAP and BiPAP: Which One is Best For You?}, url={https://www.sleepassociation.org/sleep-treatments/cpap-machines-masks/cpap-vs-bipap/}, journal={American Sleep Association}, publisher={American Sleep Association}, author={ASA Authors \&amp; ReviewersSleep Physician and American Sleep Association Reviewers}}

  @article{wright1988role,
  title={The Role of Airflow Resistance in Patients with the Adult Respiratory Distress Syndrome1-4},
  author={Wright, Patrick E and Bernard, Gordon R},
  year={1988}}

@article{broseghini1988respiratory,
  title={Respiratory resistance and intrinsic positive end-expiratory pressure (PEEPi) in patients with the adult respiratory distress syndrome (ARDS)},
  author={Broseghini, C and Brandolese, R and Poggi, R and Bernasconi, M and Manzin, E and Rossi, A},
  journal={European Respiratory Journal},
  volume={1},
  number={8},
  pages={726--731},
  year={1988},
  publisher={Eur Respiratory Soc}
}

@article{cressoni2008anatomical,
  title={Anatomical and functional intrapulmonary shunt in acute respiratory distress syndrome},
  author={Cressoni, Massimo and Caironi, Pietro and Polli, Federico and Carlesso, Eleonora and Chiumello, Davide and Cadringher, Paolo and Quintel, Micheal and Ranieri, Vito Marco and Bugedo, Guillermo and Gattinoni, Luciano},
  journal={Critical care medicine},
  volume={36},
  number={3},
  pages={669--675},
  year={2008},
  publisher={LWW}
}

  @article{yalccinkayapressure,
  title={Pressure-Volume Controlled Mechanical Ventilator: Modeling and Simulation},
  author={YAL{\c{C}}INKAYA, Fikret and YILDIRIM, Mustafa E and {\"U}NSAL, Hamza}
}

@misc{medical ventilator with lung model - matlab & simulink, title={Medical Ventilator with Lung Model}, url={https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/examples/medical-ventilator-with-lung-model.html}, journal={Medical Ventilator with Lung Model - MATLAB & Simulink}}

}

% An example of a IEEEtran control entry which can change some IEEEtran.bst
% settings. An entry like this must be cited via \bstctlcite{} command
% before the first real \cite{}. The same entry key cannot be called twice
% (just like multiple \cite{} of the same entry key place only one entry
% in the bibliography.)
% The available control fields are:

% CTLuse_article_number
% "no" turns off the display of the number for articles.
% "yes" enables

% CTLuse_paper
% "no" turns off the display of the paper and type fields in inproceedings.
% "yes" enables

% CTLuse_forced_etal 
% "no" turns off the forced use of "et al."
% "yes" enables

% CTLmax_names_forced_etal
% The maximum number of names that can be present beyond which an "et al."
% usage is forced. Be sure that CTLnames_show_etal (below)
% is not greater than this value!

% CTLnames_show_etal
% The number of names that will be shown with a forced "et al.".
% Must be less than or equal to CTLmax_names_forced_etal

% CTLuse_alt_spacing 
% "no" turns off the alternate interword spacing for entries with URLs.
% "yes" enables

% CTLalt_stretch_factor
% If alternate interword spacing for entries with URLs is enabled, this is
% the interword spacing stretch factor that will be used. For example, the
% default "4" here means that the interword spacing in entries with URLs can
% stretch to four times normal. Does not have to be an integer.

% CTLdash_repeated_names
% "no" turns off the "dashification" of repeated (i.e., identical to those
% of the previous entry) names. IEEE normally does this.
% "yes" enables

% CTLname_format_string
% The name format control string as explained in the BibTeX style hacking
% guide.
% IEEE style "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" is the default,

% CTLname_latex_cmd
% A LaTeX command that each name will be fed to (e.g., "\textsc").
% Leave empty if no special font is desired for the names.
% The default is empty.

% CTLname_url_prefix
% The prefix text used before URLs.
% The default is "[Online]. Available:" A space will be inserted after this
% text. If this space is not wanted, just use \relax at the end of the
% prefix text.


% Those fields that are not to be changed can be left out.
% @IEEEtranBSTCTL{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol,
%   CTLuse_article_number     = "yes",
%   CTLuse_paper              = "yes",
%   CTLuse_forced_etal        = "no",
%   CTLmax_names_forced_etal  = "10",
%   CTLnames_show_etal        = "1",
%   CTLuse_alt_spacing        = "yes",
%   CTLalt_stretch_factor     = "4",
%   CTLdash_repeated_names    = "yes",
%   CTLname_format_string     = "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}",
%   CTLname_latex_cmd         = "",
%   CTLname_url_prefix        = "[Online]. Available:"
% }
```

Comment: Can you find out *which* citations are missing and show the relevant `.bib` entry in your question? Possibly not relevant, but entry [5] looks fishy: It says `amp;` (which probably comes from `&amp;` the HTML escape for `&`, which would be `\&` in TeX). In any case BibTeX will only add those entries from your `.bib` file to the bibliography that were `\cite`d explicitly (you can use `\nocite{<key>}` to add specific entries without citing them and you can sue `\nocite{*}` to get all entries from the `.bib` file in the bibliography list).

Comment: Thank you for catching the &, I couldn't find where that error was coming from. I updated the question to include the .bib code, there are still some errors

Comment: you cannot have spaces in the label for bib records

Comment: @Guido could you please specify what you mean by this?

Comment: the last `@misc` entry is `@misc{medical ventilator with lung model - matlab & simulink, title={Medical Ventilator with Lung Model}, url={https://www.mathworks.com/hhe first comma elp/physmod/simscape/examples/medical-ventilator-with-lung-model.html}, journal={Medical Ventilator with Lung Model - MATLAB & Simulink}}` where the label (the string of characters immeidately after `@mis{` and before the hefirst comma `,` contains white spaces, and they are not allowed there.